# If the username is real, display the profile page. If not, don't

Tags: php, mysqli

I recently created a registration/ log in system and I would like to have a personal profile page for each user. Say if I look up this user, I want to have this user with it's own information and others can see as well. I already have that layout, but what if someone searches for a username that's not in the database? The page should be empty.

Here is my try at it, is this correct? I got this from my registration page to check if the username is taken or not. Does the same rule still apply for searching someone on the url?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>=1){
        $error = true;  
        $username_error ='<div class="error-notice">
                        <div class="oaerror danger">
                        <strong>Uh oh!</strong> - That Username is already taken. Please use a different Username.
                        </div>';


    }else{ 
     }
```

If not, may I have some help to tweak it?

Comment: your code is vulnerable to sql injection - you should try learning how to use `prepared statements`

Comment: that code should work but it's vulnerable as @RamRaider said

Answer (score 0):

I take the question to be saying that you wish to check for the existence of a user based upon a value passed in the querystring/url and display the user profile ( or similar ) if found. Is that a correct summation?

I mentioned in a comment that the code was vulnerable to sql injection - I would strongly suggest that you take the time now to get to grips with the basics of `prepared statements` rather than using variables directly embedded within the sql.

```
try{

    $validuser = false;

    $dbhost =   'localhost';
    $dbuser =   'xxx'; 
    $dbpwd  =   'xxx'; 
    $dbname =   'xxx';
    $con    =   new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );

    if( !empty( $_GET['username'] ) ){

        $username = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );


        $sql='select * from users where username=?';
        $stmt=$con->prepare( $sql );

        if( $stmt ){
            /* run the query to check username */

            /* Bind parameters to the placeholders */
            $stmt->bind_param( 's', $username );

            /* execute */
            $result = $con->execute();

            if( $result ){

                $stmt->store_result();
                $stmt->fetch();

                $rows = $stmt->num_rows;
                $validuser = ( $rows == 1 ) ? true : false;

                $stmt->free_result();
                $stmt->close();

            } else {
                throw new Exception('Query failed');
            }

        } else {
            throw new Exception('Failed to prepare sql statement');
        }
    }




    if( $validuser ){
        /* display user profile */
    } else {
        /* display message - user not found etc */
    }




}catch( Exception $e ){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```